# How to prevent ansible to acess /home/ansible/.ansible?

Tags: ansible

I'm with an infrastructure problem that makes Ansible sometimes fail when accessing `/home/ansible/.ansible`. This is a networked folder. Unfortunately can't change the user home dir.

Can I prevent ansible to access the `.ansible` file?

Comment: set remote_tmp value in ansible.cfg on another dir, you can't prevent, ansible need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have admin rights on machine in question? If yes, you can just bindmount this folder somewhere in /etc/fstab

If you don't have admin rights, fuse-based solutions might help.

For both of these https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/602496/how-to-mount-a-local-directory-without-root may help.

The other possible way is to find every variable with ~/.ansible in ansible configuration reference https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html and override it in ansible config